# how to create a generic class with "Pull to refresh" to be extended by UITableView (component)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UIView with UITableView component and I want to create a class with "Pull to refresh" method and then use that for all table view that I have. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some projects around that implement the pull to refresh mechanism. You should take a look at them.

Examples:

https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/

Comment: Thanks Bruno.. I am tryng to apply that to my project